# wagtail on-publish custom sucess message

Tags: django, wagtail, django-messages, wagtail-admin

I have a question regarding the success message wagtail is displaying when an editor is publishing a page in the admin interface. It's usually "Page {Page.title} has been published".  I’am trying to figure out how to add one’s own success or error message on-publishing resp. an error occuring. For a Page in my project I have implemented the below receiver that gets activated if the editor uploads a file via a certain field  and publishes the site. This file is then processed by a script, though the file itself is not saved.
For the editors, I would like to have a custom success message displayed below the default on-publish success message if they uploaded the file successfully, tough only if the pages is published after uplaoding a file. I found the question linked below, I could figure out how to show a custom message but it is not a very satisfying solution.

The wagtail version, I'am using is `4.22`

[customize-post-publish-flash-message-in-wagtail-cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317860/customize-post-publish-flash-message-in-wagtail-cms)

```
@receiver(page_published, sender=Model)
def process_uploaded_file(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.uploaded_file:
        process_data(instance.uploaded_file.path)
        instance.uploaded_file.delete(save=False)
        instance.uploaded_file = None
        instance.date = (date.today())
        instance.save()
```

I took the hook from the answer in the question linked above and changed it a bit. If one of the pages of my model gets edited and published it checks for the latest revision and checks within it's contents for the field 'uploaded_file' wether something was uploaded. So far that works, but it's quite unsatisfying to have the receiver for enabling the user uploading a file to refresh data (for a dashboard) and the hook for displaying a message in the admin interface if the editor has indeed done so. Both things should happen at the same place, and checking the json of the revisions seems not a good solutions.

```
def do_after_page_edit(request, page):
    if isinstance(page, MyPage) :
        latest_revision = revisions.order_by('-created_at').first()
        latest_content = latest_revision.content
        if latest_content['uploaded_file']:
            messages.success(request, f"You have updated the data to Page {page.title}")
        else:
            messages.success(request, f"You have edited and published Page {page.title} but not updated the data")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have run into the fundamental trade-off with hook architectures. Having hooks to allow programmers to add or modify behavior at certain points in a process makes the process flexible - but at the cost of having the code a bit spread out. I agree that sometimes makes it harder to keep all the pieces in your head - but it's better than monkey patching which would sentence you to revisiting that code every time you upgrade.

It looks like you are using signals and responding to a `page_published` signal. Does your code become nicer if you [use an "after_publish_page" hook](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#after-publish-page)?

Comment: To add to this answer, why not just add a method to your Page model, if that method exists, call it and use the message from that. It lets you co-locate the behaviour and still uses hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a method in my Page model as proposed above and used the "after_publish_page" hook as proposed, from which I'am calling the method. It works good and I can skip the detour of checking the revision object's content for the latest revision. Don't know why i didn't checked via `if page.uploaded_file:` wether a file was uploaded from the beginning.

```
@hooks.register('after_publish_page')
def after_publish_page(request, page):
    # Call the process_data method on the page
    if isinstance(page, DashboardSubPage):
        if page.uploaded_file:
            page.process_datafile() #call the method in the page model
                messages.success(request, f"You have updated the data to Page {page.title}")
        else:
            messages.success(request, f"You have edited and published Page {page.title} but not updated the data")
```